# Difference between Development and Distribution Provisioning Profile on Provisioning Portal?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am going to activate APNS on my app, so i am having bit confusion over following.

1. What is basic difference between Development and Distribution Provisioning Profile on Provisioning Portal
2. I am going activate APNS(Apple Push notification Service) to an Application which i am going to upload on Apple Store. what should i use?

This will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669019/iphone-development-what-is-the-difference-between-a-development-and-distributio

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just to explain a bit more, the **development** provisioning profile is for testing your App on a device (iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch), and the **distribution** profile is used when you're submitting your application to Apple to get it onto the store.

Both profiles are linked to your account as well as keychains on your computer.

If you'd like to install your software on several devices without using the App Store, you'll have to create an **Ad Hoc** distribution profile with the device ID numbers, and install that profile as well as the software, on all of the devices.

Comment: In provisioning portal: Why can I link devices to a distribution profile then? From what you say it makes totally sense for development provisioning profiles, but I dont the the reason for distribution profiles.

Comment: Note that if you want to BETA TEST your application through Apple TestFlight, you should definitely select "Distribution" profile (yes, the same option as for deploying to App Store) when signing your application.

Comment: But why does Apple care whether or not the app is a distribution version or a development version? What is the significance of choosing between these options while activating APNS for the app? GCM / WNS don't seem to care whether it's on playstore or not AFAIK.

Comment: I noticed with distribution profile you don't need to get the user to install the profile, they just need the signed IPA. if their device isn't in the used profile the app will "install" appear with the apps but will not run (with a dark icon)

Answer (score 3):

1) Development provisional profile, used for testing your app

2) Distribution provisional profile, used when you are ready to submit your app to the app store

Follow - [iPhone development - what is the difference between a development and distribution provisioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669019/iphone-development-what-is-the-difference-between-a-development-and-distributio)

Comment: Hi.. I have a doubt.. Why can't we use distribution profile only for all testing purposes?? Instead of using development and distribution we can use only distribution for all testing?? Can you explain me please?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you cant debug using a distribution profile

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1682/_index.html) Apple site states why they can't.  They're missing the entitlement `get-task-allow`.