# Is it possible to automate an app downloaded from the App Store using Appium?

Tags: appium

I am trying to automate my company's app, downloaded from App Store, on a real hardware device (iPhone) using Appium.

Looking for help. I have tried:

1. Download appium 12.2
2. installed  ios-webkit-remote-debugger
3. Downloaded the app from app store
4. Connected the iPhone with Mac
5. Entered the UDID and BundeID and Forced Device as iPhone and click on Launch.
6. Server started successfully but not able to launch the apium inspector.

Comment: Please provide the server logs. How did you know the BundleId? Was this an application you/your client put on the app store?

Comment: I have application source code from there i copied the bundle id. I got it from plist.

Comment: I spent some time testing on hardware devices this last week. Please open a separate question for how to get setup using XCode/Appium and I'll walk you through the whole setup there.

Comment: I have opened a separate post. Please guide me so that i can start working on appium, Really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Jump into the Appium chat http://appium.io/chat and we'll update the answer when we get it working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You are not able to automate a build downloaded from the App Store.**

For Instruments/Appium to connect to the application on a real device you need to....

1. Have the `.ipa` file signed with a "Development" certificate that includes the UDID of the target device
2. You can **not** use a "Distribution" certificate, which is what **all** App Store builds are signed with

Source: I spent the last two days on this. I need to update the Appium documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "Development certificate that includes the UDID of the target device"?

Comment: When you code sign your .ipa during archiving, you need to choose a Development certificate. This is what developers use to sign their apps when they run them on their phones during development. Difference between development and distribution certificates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/669068/3622606)

Comment: Right, but the certificate doesn't include any UDID. The provisioning profile does. Certificate only includes reference to the provisioning profile. I need to understand this part: "that includes the UDID of the target device"

Comment: your development certificate needs to reference a mobile provisioning profile that allows you to build to the device you're trying to automate on. Test: Build and Run to that device via Xcode with the Code Signing identity you'll use when you archive the .ipa. If that Build and Run works, then the .ipa will work when you try and automate.

Comment: can you please update the answer wrt XCUITest from Instruments ?

Comment: This was the accepted answer in 2014, is it still true, since I was informed a colleague at work had managed to automate an app store app using appium?

Comment: I haven't worked with appium since 2014. iOS automation has moved forward a lot since then. My speculation is that this answer requires validation and editing.