# Difference between Development, Production, Development Provisioning Profile and Distribution Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

This question is similar to : [iPhone development - what is the difference between a development and distribution provisioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669019/iphone-development-what-is-the-difference-between-a-development-and-distributi)

I understood the Development and Distribution Provisioning Profiles uses.

But i con't understood what is the use to create Development, Production certificates in Certificates option.

And what is the main difference between **Development, Production certificates in Certificates option and Development and Distribution in Provisioning Profiles option?.**

And one more is Can we create **N number** of cretificates for each?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you want to distribute ipa or Diawi to other users or you want to run app on your testing device than you need development certificates but if you want to upload app to app store for test flight or release than you need distribution certificate

the first section is for development machine you are using (i.e for MAC)

means it is for mac certification the mac you are using is for development or for distribution when you create certification you are given private keys which is stored in your keychain

and last sections is for app means the app you are making is just for development or for release

when you create certification in first section each certificate is having team id using that team id you create provisioning certificates in second section

which must be matched with team id certification stored in keychain

Comment: what is the main difference between Development, Production certificates in Certificates option and Development and Distribution in Provisioning Profiles option?.

Comment: See the above image There is development and production in Certificates and Development and Distribution in Provisioning, Can you please explain difference between Development in Certificates and Development in Provisioning?